# Excel file values change when imported to google colab using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, google-colaboratory

My excel file values change for the specific column :- "CUSIP" when I import it to my google colab using pandas. The rows also are not same as the excel file and they interchange. I am not able to figure out why the values and rows are changing.

[image: The python code to importExcel file]

I expected the dataframe to return same values as the excel file but it did not. For ex:- the first cusip value is 8767100 but no value like that exist in excel fle. I think pandas  is adding zeros or modifying values in the cusip row and Im not able to figure that[image: search 8767100]

The cusip values are starting with 087671D4 and exist like that. But in dataframe it is changed

Comment: You want `pd.read_excel("...xlsx", dtype={"cusip": str})` and not a *post* `.astype(str)`.

Comment: No there is no change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example